# Searchkick memory leak

Tags: searchkick

Running `rake searchkick:reindex  CLASS=Product` for an application causes the Rake process to leak memory; after about 15-20 minutes it's bad enough to freeze a Debian system with 16GB of RAM. There are ~3800 "Product" records.

I managed to work around this problem with the following code in a Rake task:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
res = connection.execute('select max(id) from products')
id = res.getvalue(0,0)
1.upto(id) do |i|
  p = Product.find_by_id(i)
  next unless p

  p.reindex
end
```

This is also a little quicker.

Can anyone suggest a means to investigate this memory leak? It would be useful to do so in more detail before considering opening a ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This causes a problem with generating indexes: [Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951968/text-fields-are-not-optimised-for-operations-that-require-per-document-field-dat/72046472#72046472)

That problem can be fixed by adding the following to the code above:

```
Product.reindex(import: false)
# Rest of code goes here...
```