# Searchkick::InvalidQueryError (Bad mapping - run Record.reindex)

Tags: searchkick

Another problem caused by moving to Opensearch (1.3.1, Mac homebrew) from Elasticsearch for a Rails 6 app.

```
Loading test environment (Rails 6.1.4.7)
>> r = Record.find(638205575)
  Record Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 638205575], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Record id: 638205575, created_at: "2022-04-22 08:47:01.931397000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-04-22 08:47:01.931397000 +0000", metadata: {...
>> Record.search(r.name)
  Record Search (12.2ms)  records_test/_search {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"multi_match":{"query":"Eighth Record","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Eighth Record","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Eighth Record","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Eighth Record","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}}]}}]}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":10000}
Traceback (most recent call last):
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError (Bad mapping - run Record.reindex)
```

I can't see anything in that output that indicates in what way the query is invalid or the mapping is bad. Actually running `Record.reindex` doesn't show any errors and simply responds with `true` in the console.

Can anyone see anything that might offer any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem was related to [Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951968/text-fields-are-not-optimised-for-operations-that-require-per-document-field-dat) and, ultimately, to [Searchkick memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334743/searchkick-memory-leak).

Substituting a custom rake task for `rake searchkick:reindex:all` caused the indexes not to be built correctly. For example, here's an sdiff of the two different outcomes (correct index from the searchkick task on the right):

```
"records_development" : {                       |   "records_development_20220425162622176" : {
    "aliases" : { },                                          |     "aliases" : {
                                                              >       "records_development" : { }
                                                              >     },
    "mappings" : {                                                  "mappings" : {
                                                              >       "dynamic_templates" : [
                                                              >         {
                                                              >           "string_template" : {
                                                              >             "match" : "*",
                                                              >             "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                                                              >             "mapping" : {
                                                              >               "fields" : {
                                                              >                 "analyzed" : {
                                                              >                   "analyzer" : "searchkick_index",
                                                              >                   "index" : true,
                                                              >                   "type" : "text"
                                                              >                 }
                                                              >               },
                                                              >               "ignore_above" : 30000,
                                                              >               "type" : "keyword"
                                                              >             }
                                                              >           }
                                                              >         }
                                                              >       ],
      "properties" : {                                                "properties" : {
        "abbreviation" : {                                              "abbreviation" : {
          "type" : "text",                                    |           "type" : "keyword",
                                                              >           "ignore_above" : 30000,
          "fields" : {                                                    "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {                                     |             "analyzed" : {
              "type" : "keyword",                             |               "type" : "text",
              "ignore_above" : 256                            |               "analyzer" : "searchkick_index"
                                                              >             },
                                                              >             "word_middle" : {
                                                              >               "type" : "text",
```